# Diferença velocidade em HD Sata/SSD

Tags: banco-de-dados, desempenho, mongodb

Tenho o MongoDB rodando numa HD SSD de 500GB.

Mas como a pasta /data começou a ficar muito grande, colocamos uma HD *slave* de 3TB, mas essa sendo SATA e não SSD como a primeira.

Mas após mudar a pasta data pra essa nova HD, notamos uma diferença considerável na performance. Será que essa queda de performance se deu pela simples mudança de SSD para SATA? Eu até imaginei que teria uma diferença pequena, mas não uma diferença grande.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Primeiro vou considerar que o dispositivo de 500GB é um SSD. Ou ele é SSD (Solid State Drive) ou ele é HDD (Hard Disk Drive). Até existe o HDD vendido como HDD SSD, mas no fundo ele é apenas um HDD que possui um módulo SSD para fazer um cache interno. Há algum ganho, mas é mínimo. Isto é chamado de HDD híbrido, apesar de ser um engano chamar assim.

SSD existe principalmente para dar mais velocidade. Ele custa <strike>consideravelmente</strike> mais caro que um HDD. Qual é a razão das pessoas pagarem mais caro por algo? Tem que ter uma vantagem clara. Algumas pessoas até vão considerar que há menor consumo de energia, outros vão considerar que ele é menos suscetível à falhas (embora também possam durar menos para gravação), há até quem veja o tamanho reduzido uma vantagem para notebooks e servidores de alta densidade. Mas a maior vantagem é a velocidade.

Um SSD costuma ter velocidade final sequencial de 5 à 25 vezes maior em relação a um HDD normal. Isto não muda muito em relação ao HDD "híbrido". É uma diferença brutal.

Mas o maior ganho de velocidade é no tempo de acesso. O que para banco de dados, que faz mais acesso randômico, algo extremamente importante. Como o SSD é uma memória randômica pura e o HDD é um disco, a mecânica de acesso é completamente diferente, dando uma vantagem para o SSD de pelo menos 100 vezes. Há casos extremos que chega até a 1000 vezes. E nem estou falando da (não tão) nova geração de SSD baseada em RAM, já há dispositivos comercializados 10 ou 100 vezes mais rápidos que os SSDs tradicionais, e há em laboratório algo quase na mesma velocidade da RAM normal, e até mais rápido... louco!

Fique de olhos nas [NVRAMs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-volatile_random-access_memory).

[image: SSD NVe]

O acesso a um dado ao disco precisa fazer deslocamento da cabeça de leitura/gravação para chegar na trilha correta, e precisa esperar o disco girar e se posicionar no *cluster* onde está o dado. Esse tempo é muito rápido para padrões humanos, mas para padrões computacionais, parece uma eternidade.

Um disco é algo mecânico e embora falemos que ele pode fazer acesso randômico, nunca é randômico de fato. É apenas sequencial otimizado. É melhor que uma fita, por exemplo, que o acesso 100% sequencial (complexidade O(n)). O SSD é eletrônico, por isso ele pode ser 100% randômico (complexidade O(1)).

Um banco de dados, na maior parte do tempo, faz acessos às páginas de dados espalhadas pelo *drive*, afinal eles trabalham com árvores, ou em raros casos com *buckets* de dados, que não são sequenciais, pelo contrário, ser bastante espalhado é a grande vantagem.

A enorme diferença é justamente pela troca. O barato saiu caro. Antes de tomar decisões deve-se pesquisar e obter informações confiáveis, decidir baseado em especulação só traz malefícios.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Grato pelo seu esclarecimento Ainda bem que no nosso caso, ainda temos opção de testar outras opções. Obrigado.