# Servidor de aplicação

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, sql-server, iis, cliente-servidor

O cliente não tem servidor (Windows Server ou Linux) e não quer hospedar o sistema em um *data center* ou nas nuvens por exemplo, e deseja usar o sistema em uma intranet.

No momento 3 funcionários usarão o sistema que está sendo desenvolvido em MVC e SQL Server.

Inicialmente precisamos de um servidor somente para a hospedar o sistema de gestão e o banco de dados.

Dúvidas:

Qual o hardware necessário aconselhável para esse cenário (memória RAM, processador, etc.)?

Qual a versão do sistema: Windows Server XXXXX? Windows 10 funciona como servidor?

Answer (score 8):

Sei lá se isto está no escopo, mas dá para responder parcialmente e acho que será útil.

> não quer hospedar o sistema em um data center ou nas nuvens

Não conheço o caso específico, mas ele parece ser sensato.

Qualquer sistema operacional *mainstream* funcionará, mas o ideal é que um criado para ser um servidor funciona melhor. Então iria de Windows Server mais atual possível 2012 ou se der tempo pode pegar o 2016.

Se achar que tem alguma vantagem para seu caso pode pensar no Linux e rodar o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) e o [SQL Server](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/cloud-platform/sql-server-on-linux?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Não é possível dizer os requerimentos de hardware sem conhecer profundamente qual será a carga que será usada em detalhes e requisitos de performance, confiabilidade, etc. Desta forma, eu só diria quanto mais, melhor. Se o custo for o mais importante, quanto menos, melhor.

Simulações podem ser úteis. Claro que precisa saber fazer isso adequadamente, mas parece que qualquer coisa básica vai dar conta. Um melhor garantirá o futuro.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vale lembrar que para bancos o importante é um IO alto ou seja, discos rígidos com uma taxa de leitura e escrita alta, se possível SSD, mas ai o custo sobe exponencialmente. também importante memoria, dependendo de como ira trabalhar com o banco, uma quantidade razoável de memoria é o principal, já processador não me preocuparia tanto, mas claro com bom senso.

Comment: Sem dúvida, eu acho estranho hoje um servidor que não tenha SSD. Tem que ter um motivo muito forte para não ter. Ainda que em certos casos muito simples possa ser até exagero. Memória é das coisas mais importantes que existe. Acho curioso muito programador não saber disso. Observação mais que corretas.

Comment: Estive dando uma olhada no HD SSD e realmente é algo muito superior ao HD convencional e o preço também é superior.

Comment: Se for SSD mesmo, não é HDD.

Comment: @AdrianoSUV A sigla HD vem de Hard Drive, Disco Rígido, por ter dentro do HD um disco "rigido" rs.. ja a sigla SSD vem de State Solide Drive, ou Unidade de estado solido, então ou se fala SSD ou HD, existem modelos que combinam HD e SSD, mas não recomendo para servidor.

Comment: Na verdade a sigla HD é High Definition. HDD é Hard Disk Drive. Existe o SSHD - Solid State Hard Drive que é híbrido (no fundo é um HDD com uma camada de SSD fazendo um grande cache).

Comment: @bigown, até pouco tempo atrás trabalhei com vendas de servidores HP, pensando em um servidor para banco de dados, o que complica a utilização de SSD é o alto custo comparado com a capacidade, sendo que um servidor dedicado para banco de dados, necessita e muito de espaço, logo as empresas acabam se assustando e muito com a diferença de valores entre os HDs convencionais e SSD. E quando se fala em investimento em TI, boa parte das empresas entendem como custo, não veem o benefício de terem um equipamento melhor e que dê mais desempenho.

Comment: Eu assusto com a diferença de performance. Chega ser mais de 200X mais rápido nos casos mais extremos. Mesmo em casos onde o ganho não é grande, costuma passar de 10X. Pode haver algum motivo, mas economizar nisso, na minha opinião, em geral é uma visão tosca. Só tem gente incompetente cuidado de TI.

Comment: Relacionado http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127715/101

Answer (score 2):

Adriano, como apenas 3 usuários usarão a aplicação, uma máquina de 4gb de RAM, disco de 7200rpm e 2 x64 cores de mais 2GHz dedicada apenas para isso pode dar conta do recado sim.

De acordo com esse [guia](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506.aspx) sobre os requirimentos do SQL Server, o recomendado para o express é 1GB (acredito que será usado o SQL Express já que são apenas 3 usuários). Este outro [artigo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc268240.aspx) da Microsoft diz que para servidores ISS de alto volume devem ter no mínimo de 2gb a 4gb, logo, 1gb no seu caso vai ser o suficiente. O Windows 10 tem um mínimo de 2gb de RAM na versão x64 e o um processador de 1GHz, somando 4gb certinho contando com os outros requerimentos.

O Windows 10 pode ser usado como servidor de aplicação sim, apesar que seria bem melhor um Windows Server 2008 ou superior quem foi designado para essa função. As formas que conheço para hostear uma aplicação no Windows 10 são:

1. Instalar o ISS no Windows 10 e hostear normalmente. [Exemplo](http://www.howtogeek.com/112455/how-to-install-iis-8-on-windows-8/)
2. Docker - Colocar sua aplicação em um container e instalar o docker no Windows 10. [Exemplo](http://dotnetliberty.com/index.php/2015/10/25/asp-net-5-running-in-docker-on-windows/)
3. Kestrel e dotnet core - Utilizar o dotnet core e o kestrel webserver
   para criar um serviço. [Exemplo](http://tostring.it/2016/01/12/Using-Kestrel-with-ASPNET-5/)

Comment: Desculpe mas discordo totalmente com sua resposta. Ao trabalhar com windows 10 como servidor, você não tem nem 10% do que um windows server pode te proporcionar, tirando ainda a segurança duvidosa do windows 10. processador de 1ghz? hoje em dia difícil encontrar algum modelo novo nessa faixa em, 1 gb de ram? com certeza ira ficar muito travado isso é se subir né. tirando que memoria de 2gb somente  ddr2 e olha la. hoje já estamos em ddr4. acredito que se for para fazer algo que faça direito.

Comment: Tem razão @ThomasErichPimentel suas observações são muito valiosas, porém essa é uma alternativa de baixo custo para o Cliente pois no final esse Cliente está pensando no custo do servidor e não no beneficio e o *barato sai caro!* sei disso. Vou alerta-lo, apesar de tudo o Cliente tem uma máquina parecida com a que o Felipe sugeriu, estou analisando fazer alguns testes (com um processador e memória RAM mais potente).

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel eu sei que o Windows não traz as capacidade de um Windows Server, mas a pergunta do usuário inclui "Windows 10 funciona como servidor ?" e a resposta é sim independente disso. Referente às especificações, todo meu segundo parágrafo é embasado de artigos officiais da microsoft. O requerimento mínimo do Windows 10 é 1GHz sim (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications#sysreqs). Note que eu menciono uma máquina de 4gb de RAM, não de 2gb ou 1gb.

Comment: A Microsoft não sabe qual é a aplicação que irá rodar ali. Ela diz o que é o mínimo para funcionar alguma coisa mínima. A Microsoft não cometeria o erro de recomendar algo tão específico para alguém sem conhecer o caso concreto em profundidade.

Comment: Bom, nesse critério ele pode usar um XP também, sobra mais recurso da máquina para processar e servir os dados do que com o 10.

Comment: @Bacco concordo plenamente, ainda que eu tenha restrições ao XP, tem razão, se é para economizar e não se preocupar com o que é mais adequado, o XP é ótimo. Só pode pode aparecer alguém aqui e falar que o 98 tb dá, aí não, né?!?!!! :D O XP já é um SO de verdade.

Comment: @bigown Aí acho que a camada de rede vai dar uma atrapalhadinha, pra falar a verdade, nem lembro se dá pra usar IPV6 nesses :)

Comment: XP na minha opnião se nao o melhor, foi um dos melhores sistemas lançados pela Microsoft. Agora cara, se a questão e baixo custo, a HP tem umas soluções boas para servidor. coisa de 2 mil reais você adquire um, veja o link: http://www.kabum.com.br/produto/62569/servidor-hp-g2020t-gen8-pentium-2-5ghz-3mb-4gb-microsvr-787242-s05/?tag=servidor%20hp, caso de pra gastar um pouco mais: http://www.kabum.com.br/produto/69549/servidor-hp-iss-ml110-gen9-quad-core-xeon-e5-1603v3-2-8-ghz-10mb-8gb-1000gb-350w-799112-s05/?tag=servidor%20hp

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel para o hardware, se a pessoa tá começando, tem umas empresas especializadas em Xeon usado a bom preço que eu gosto muito em São Paulo, com garantia e tudo. Só dar uma pesquisada. (claro que é para dar um Jumpstart no negócio só, o ideal é ir pro zerado o quanto antes).

Comment: @Bacco verdade, entre um Xeon usado e um Pentium novo, com certeza vou de Xeon.

Comment: Vai ser bem legal usar Windows desktop em um Xeon :D

Comment: O ideal seria um Server Core no Xeon, ou melhor, nano server, ai seria perfeito.

Comment: Vejo que não há uma unanimidade em relação ao assunto e depois que postei a pergunta decidi rever com o cliente sobre a computação em nuvem.

Comment: Usar na nuvem seria o melhor nesse caso com certeza.